# calling data from axios in react causes error

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm new to using Axios so I figured I would use it with React to make a small PWA just for fun and to learn it. The function is simple press button info get's displayed. When I'm trying to display the info in the return() i get an error saying it can't read the property of the api endpoint so I think what is happening is it's trying to render it before the function is being called. I assume this is a good use for async / await but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Here is the code

```
const IndexPage = () => {
  const [data, getData] = useState([])

  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://dad-jokes.p.rapidapi.com/random/joke',
    headers: {
      'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'dad-jokes.p.rapidapi.com',
      'X-RapidAPI-Key': '17fb7de893msh59a82cece7f697ap1c0305jsn0e7db5ca2d76'
    }
  };
  
    function jokes() {
      axios.request(options).then((res) =>  {
      console.log(res.data);
      const data =  res.data
      getData(data)
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }

  return (
    <Layout>
      <main className="full-page">
        <div className="center">
          <cite>Press for the best dad jokes around!</cite>
          <button onClick={jokes}> Get Jokes</button>

          <h4>{data.body[0].setup}</h4> // this is running before function is being called onClick.
          <p>{data.body[0].punchline}</p> 
        </div>
      </main>
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

thank you in advance!

Comment: Why is your `setData()` function called `getData()`? Second time I've seen it this week. Is there a tutorial out there that's telling people to do this? [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) clearly call this a setter. The "get" is when you read the value.

Comment: Can you show the word-for-word error? Are you sure it's not complaining that `body` doesn't exist?

Comment: No, no tutorial I followed or anything I just saw some examples on line when trying to solve my issue and saw it.

Comment: Would you mind linking the example?

Comment: sure I can look for it! Also the error just says cannot read properties of undefined then points to the h4. I think it's because the data from the axios request isn't called until the button is clicked so there is no {data.body[0].setup} yet to be referenced.

Comment: Yes, that's why, I just misunderstood what you meant when you said "it can't read the property of the api endpoint" . Adding an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  const [data, getData] = useState([])
```

Should be called `setData`. See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

On first run, `data` is set to `[]`, an empty array. Later on,

```
   <h4>{data.body[0].setup}</h4>
```

You try to read `body[0].setup` from the array. This line is equivalent to `[].body[0].setup`.

You can use the [optional chaining operator (`?.`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) here:

```
   <h4>{data?.body?.[0]?.setup}</h4>
```

Which will evaluate to `undefined` instead of complaining "can't read property of undefined".

Comment: This worked perfectly so is this the correct way for it to be handled or is my code just off so this is a work around?

Comment: @Brandon.b this is one way of doing it. A more general solution is to have another state called `isLoading`. If `isLoading`, then display a spinner or just nothing. If not `isLoading`, the data should all be ready, so just display everything. It depends on your needs, in this case this solution is fine but if we had to decide whether or not to load a component, the other solution might be easier.

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate thee answer and the information you've provided you rock. so if I went the isLoading solution then it would be a basic if statement then would the if statemeent wrap the function how would it know to differentiate between when isLoading finishes and then displays the result?

Comment: haha no worries, glad I could help.